# Attached file contains page's content

Tags: c#, asp.net, attachment

So, I'm trying to transmit a file to the client. Following some other SO answers, I currently have the following code (sb is a `StringBuilder`) :

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();

HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=export.csv");
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";

HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
```

However, my issue is that I get the expeted result, and then the source code of the page that contains my button is appended to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a

```
Response.End();
```

after your code. if not, Asp.Net will keep on processing the page, which can result in what happens to you.

Comment: I have to wait 10-15 minutes before accepting an answer. I'm also trying to understand if the difference between the 2 answers is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

```
string attachment = string.Empty;
HttpResponse Response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=export.csv");
Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
Response.Write(sb.ToString());
Response.End();
```

Comment: Is there any reason to do `HttpResponse Response = HttpContext.Current.Response`? I mean, outside of being easier to work with.

Comment: If you are within your page, `this.Response` is the same as `HttpContext.Current.Response`. if you are e.g. within an helper class...

Comment: `HttpContext, Encapsulates all HTTP-specific information about an individual HTTP Request`. you can do some reading on the MSDN for `HttpContext.Current`

Comment: I could have also don't the following without Declaring Response 
`Response.ClearContent()` If you want to find out more information about `HTTPContext` then you can inspect all the properties that are available when you are locally debugging

Comment: @MethodMan Let me rephrase that : Does creating a new `HttpResponse myResponse` have any benefit over simply using `HttpContext.Current.Response`. Basically, what is the purpose of your 2nd line.

Comment: Readability.. @JulienBlanchard

Comment: @MethodMan k thanks a lot, I ended up acception Gian's though since he answered first and the only difference between the 2 was the readability factor.

Comment: it does note create a new HttpResponse, it assign (for readability) `HttpContext.Current.Response` to a local variable `myResponse`

Comment: @GianPaolo you mean `Does not vs Does note` just don't want to confuse readers reading the comments

Comment: Does not, of course! (it's too late to edit previous comment)